# EF child record inserts new row in parent table with hasoptional

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The problem I have is that on inserting new VehicleCategoryId of VehicleCategory table should be just inserted into CategoryId field of Vehicle table (and it is correctly).

At the same time a new record is also inserted in VehicleCategory table with new VehicleCategoryId while it shouldn't. Vehicle table should just used already existing key from VehicleCategory table.

Here's my confirguration:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleCategory VehicleCategory { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleCategory
{
    public int VehicleCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public VehicleConfiguration()
{
    this.ToTable("Vehicle");
    this.HasKey(x => x.VehicleId);
    this.HasOptional(x => x.VehicleCategory).WithMany(x => x.Vehicles).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
}

public VehicleCategoryConfiguration()
{
    this.ToTable("VehicleCategory");
    this.HasKey(x => x.VehicleCategoryId);
}
```

Insert bit:

```
this.repository.Insert(Mapper.Map<Vehicle>(vehicleModel));
```

All property values for vehicleModel come from UI form.

Comment: I see no INSERT here. Check if the view has an INSTEAD OF Trigger which also inserts into another table

Comment: By default when you add an entity to the context the related entities are added.

Comment: @Pawel I cannot modify the database so how can I avoid inserting a record in parent table?

Comment: You did not show how you insert the entity to the database so I just speculate but basically if you don't create the releationship before you add the entity to the context the EF won't have anything to insert so it won't insert.

Comment: @Pawel I have added insert statement to my original post. It's pretty straightforward, it's mapping fine.